# SQL Server Join to get Employee Details

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have table with Resigned Employee data as following,

```
EmpID      LocationID     JoinDate        ResignDate           Dept
1000          NY          12/12/2009       30/12/2012          Accounting
1001          NY          11/12/2009       30/11/2012          Accounting
1002          NY          10/10/2010       30/12/2012          IT
```

I just need to get the result for the Employee who resigned from Dept and Location(both should be same)with Date period should be less than other resigned employee's resigned Date Period

Above Eg :

I need to get result:

1001 Record as 1001 resigned from NY & Accounting within Date Period of Employee 1000,

Please help me out to create query,

Comment: Please describe what you tried so far - it would be helpful if you posted the SQL query/ies you tried.

Comment: So you want to get employee data for employee 1001, but the date period of employee 1000? Why? I also assume you do not mean to have Dept and Location to be the same (Location=Dept?!?) I think you should clarify what you really want and also provide more data about your table structure. In the title it says `join`. Maybe you should post some structure and content data of the other table that needs to be joined?

Answer (score 0):

```
select e1.*
from employers e1 join employers e2
on e1.LocatrionID = e2.LocationID and e1.Dept = e2.Dept
where e1.resigndate < e2.resigndate
```